# Структура папок в ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

При разработке CMS на ASP.NET MVC 3 в какой директории лучше создавать папку администраторской панели вместе с ее стилями, картинками и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

asp.net mvc предоставляет отличную структуру папок:

- данные(большенство классов) в папку Model
- контроллеры(то что наследуется от Controller) в папку Controllers
- представления во Views
- стили, картинки и всё остальное в папку Content

в вашем случае уже в этих папках создать подпапки по назначению и выполняемым функциям